Как запретить макрос с пустым аргументом?
Заметил, что могу передать пустой аргумент вместо нормального для параметра макроса. Можно ли запретить такое поведение, сделав в таком случае ошибку компиляции?
#define AtLeastOneArg(arg, ...) arg

int main() {
  AtLeastOneArg(;, ;); // compiles - OK
  AtLeastOneArg(;);    // compiles - OK
  AtLeastOneArg();     // compiles - unexpected
}


можно использовать макрос, чтобы принудительно требовать хотя бы один аргумент. Можно сделать это с помощью макроса, который проверяет количество аргументов и вызывает ошибку компиляции, если аргументов недостаточно. static_assert(sizeof(#__VA_ARGS__) > 1, "At least one argument is required") и используйте его в скобках вашей начальной функции

@RevolucionforMonica не, мне надо чтобы не в __VA_ARGS__ был как минимум 1, а чтобы arg был непустой, т.е. чтобы последний вызов был невалидным, а предпоследний ок. И при этом чтобы "сигнатура" макроса была такой а не просто ... (чтобы первый аргумент имел имя)

#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y

#define NONEMPTY(...) CAT(DETAIL_NONEMPTY_,__VA_OPT__(0))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DETAIL_NONEMPTY_() DETAIL_EXPECTED_NONEMPTY_ARG(x)
#define DETAIL_NONEMPTY_0(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define DETAIL_EXPECTED_NONEMPTY_ARG()

Теперь NONEMPTY() - ошибка, а NONEMPTY(42) раскрывается в 42.
#define AtLeastOneArg(arg, ...) NONEMPTY(arg)

Как обычно, если вы пользуетесь MSVC, не забудьте /std:c++latest /Zc:preprocessor чтобы включить поддержку __VA_OPT__ (или 20 вместо latest).

Ошибка прикольная конечно в таком случае :D
error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation

@borg Ага. :) Не знаю другого нормального способа вызвать ошибку в макросе.

А кстати почему CAT юзает CAT_ а не сразу конкатенирует?

@borg #define A B, CAT_(A,42) = A42, но CAT(A,42) = B42. Именно в этом ответе разницы может и нет, но привычка всегда писать в два слоя на всякий случай осталась.
